# Pass values from array to a function

Tags: php, bbedit

I have the following code which gets all news:

```
private function get_news()
    {   
        $news = array();

        $query  = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `news_id` DESC");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $news[] = $row;
        }

        return $news;
    }
```

In the same class I have a `bbedit()` function. I want to get the value of `$news`[*int*]`['news_content']` and pass it to that function `bbedit()`.

Comment: And what is your question? `$this->bbedit($news[0]['news_content'])`...?

Comment: I want to do it for all `$news[int]['news_content]`, because then I assign them as variables to smarty. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$this` to call a function within class:

```
private function bbedit(){
    $news = $this->get_news(); // news will have all your array
    foreach($news as $key => $val){
        // do something with $val['news_content'];
    }
}
```

or

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $news[] = $this->bbedit($row['news_content']);
}
```

Comment: I just cannot think of the loop I need. Something like 
while(...){
 $news[int]['news_content'] = $this->bbedit('old_news_content');
}

Comment: Updated my answer. Is this what you are looking for?>